# Animated clouds and plane

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, animation

I have been created a simple apps, with a lot of Javascript code, I use jQuery too and the code looks so dirty. So now, I want to try restructure my code to Object-Oriented. What I've confused is where to  call a properties, where to put an user action to an element, where to put dom element variable, etc. It's a bit of my code before and after restructure.

**Before:**

```
var $cloud = $(".js-cloud");
var $plane = $(".js-plane");

function randomPosition(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$cloud.each(function(){
    var leftPosition = randomPosition(1,100) + "%";
    $(this).css("left",leftPosition)

    var speed = $(this).data("speed");
    $(this).velocity({
        left : "-200px"
    }, {
        duration : speed,
        easing : "linear",
        loop : true
    })
})


function loopPlane(){
    $plane.velocity({
        left : "-300px"
    }, {
        duration : 7000,
        easing : "linear",
        complete : function(){
            $(this).css({
                "right" : "-300px",
                "left" : "auto"
            })
            loopPlane()
        },
        delay : 15000
    })
}
loopPlane()
```

**After:**

```
//Clouds and plane element
var $cloud = $(".js-cloud");
var $plane = $(".js-plane");

/* Module */
var background = {
    init : function(){
        this.loopClouds();
        this.loopPlane();   
    },

    randomPosition : function(min,max){
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    },

    loopPlane : function(){
        var obj = this;
       //Animate it
        $plane.velocity({
            left : "-300px"
        }, {
            duration : 7000,
            easing : "linear",
            complete : function(){
                $plane.css({
                    "right" : "-300px",
                    "left" : "auto"
                })
                obj.loopPlane()
            },
            delay : 1000
        }) 
    },

    loopClouds : function(){
        var obj = this;
        $cloud.each(function(){
            var leftPosition = obj.randomPosition(1,100) + "%";
            $(this).css("left",leftPosition)

            var speed = $(this).data("speed");
            //Animate it
            $(this).velocity({
                left : "-200px"
            }, {
                duration : speed,
                easing : "linear",
                loop : true
            })
        })  
    }
}
```

Is that my code look cleaner and readable? or there is a better version of my restructure code?

Comment: looks fine with me, just the name of the class "background" whould I change. Exmple backgroundAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$var.each`, should you not be using the first parameter of the callback to target elements, instead of using `this` to target the `$var` array. If it's anything like a `.forEach` (but with an `fn.init` array), then the element is passed through the callback into the context of the loop.

You do this:

```
function loopClouds() {
    var obj = this;
    $cloud.each(function(){
        var leftPosition = obj.randomPosition(1,100) + "%";
        $(this).css("left",leftPosition)

        var speed = $(this).data("speed");
        //Animate it
        $(this).velocity({
            left : "-200px"
        }, {
            duration : speed,
            easing : "linear",
            loop : true
        })
    }); 
}
```

Shouldn't you be doing this?

```
function loopClouds() {
    $cloud.each(function (cloud) {
        cloud.css("left", randomPosition(1, 100));
        cloud.velocity({left: "-200px"}, {
            duration: cloud.data("speed"),
            easing: "linear",
            loop: true
        });
    });
}
```

This is just one example, but your usage of the `this` keywords seems to be a bit shoddy all-round.